# Obtener ruta más corta con el algoritmo de Floyd y Warshall C

Tags: c

Necesito saber cuál es la ruta más corta, en kilómetros, que hay entre una ciudad origen y otra destino. Las ciudades y las distancias las cargo al programa, mediante un fichero que tengo creado, en la primera opción del menú. La segunda es que introduciendo la ciudad origen y destino, me tiene que decir cuál es la ruta más corta en kilómetro.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
case 1:
        if((fichero = fopen("carreteras.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fallo al intentar abrir el fichero. \n");
        } else {
            bufferNodo[0] = '#';
            fscanf(fichero,"%s",bufferNodo);
            numNodo = malloc((strlen(bufferNodo) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(numNodo, bufferNodo);

            while (bufferNodo[0] != '#') {
                n = nuevo(n, numNodo);
                fscanf(fichero,"%s",bufferNodo);
                numNodo = malloc((strlen(bufferNodo) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(numNodo, bufferNodo);
                contNodos++;
            }
            while (!feof(fichero)) {
                fscanf(fichero,"%s",bufferOrigen);
                origen = malloc((strlen(bufferOrigen) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(origen, bufferOrigen);

                fscanf(fichero,"%s",bufferDestino);
                destino = malloc((strlen(bufferDestino) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(destino, bufferDestino);

                fscanf(fichero,"%s",bufferDistancia);
                distancia = malloc((strlen(bufferDistancia) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(distancia, bufferDistancia);

                if((aux_origen = buscar(n, origen)) != NULL) {
                    if((aux_destino = buscar(n, destino)) != NULL) {
                        arco(aux_origen, aux_destino, distancia);
                    } else {
                        aux_destino = buscar(n, destino);
                        arco(aux_origen, aux_destino, distancia);
                    }
                }
                printf("\nCiudad origen: %s\nCiudad destino: %s\nDistancia: %s\n", origen, destino, distancia);
                printf("\n--------------------------");
            }
        }
        fclose(fichero);
break;
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es en el case cuando leas las lineas que deben tener el formato a b c guardarlo en un arreglo path[][]

(creo que es asi un ejemplo digo

```
fgets(caracteres,100,archivo);
printf("%s",caracteres);
```

). 
Luego aplicar el algoritmo floydWarshall como una funcion como sigue:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cn; i++)
    path[i][i] = 0;

for(int k = 0; k < cn; k++)
    for(int i = 0; i < cn; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < cn; j++){
            int dt = path[i][k] + path[k][j];
            if(path[i][j] > dt)
                path[i][j] = dt;
        }
```

Esto lo haces al terminar el case 1 o al principio del 2 como gustes. Creas un flag para saber si has llamado a la funcion tanto en el case 1 como en el 2(por flag entiendase bool pero dado que en c no existe hazlo con un entero 1-true & 0-false). Haces otra funcion para saber la distancia simplemente le pasas los parametros origen y destino y devuelves path en esas variables. Espero que ahora sea todo mas claro y disculpa por la respuesta de ayer era incorrecta.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que tengo que pasarle la ciudad origen y destino y eso es lo que me tiene confuso. Porque en el fichero que cargo en la opción 1, están las ciudades nodo y después las ciudades origen, destino y distancia. Eso lo separo bien y lo almaceno correctamente en sus variables correspondientes, pero el problema es conseguir la opción 2 porque no se como tengo que hacerlo.

Comment: explicame bien lo que hace tu codigo. primero almacenas las cuidades y luego las cuidades origen?? que qieres decir

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78608/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-rivas-obtener-ruta-mas-corta-con-el-algoritmo-de-fl).

Comment: @Jorgesys lo sé, lo que pasa es que no tenía la suficiente reputación como para poder trasladarlo a un chat, al poco la conseguí y lo pude trasladar a un chat.

Comment: Excelente @chuches trata de conseguir más reputación en el sitio para que también visites el [chat],saludos!!!.

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias y trataré de ayudar más y conseguir mayor reputación. Un saludo!